# Background Music Stopping in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a small game in python using turtle and was wanting to implement some background music. This is my code (it's just at the beginning of the program)

`winsound.PlaySound("music.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC)`

The problem is that every time another song plays, interrupting the background music, and it doesn't continue afterwards.

Comment: you will have to find differ module which has `mixer` to mix sounds. maybe you should use `PyGame` instead of `Turlte` - it is better for creating games and it has modules `pygame.mixer` and `pygame.mixer.music`